# Error in running my Python Script

Tags: python, osx-lion, python-imaging-library, macports

I just updated my OS from Snow Leopard to LION 10.7.3, and I usually run this python script using IDLE. However, when I try running it, I get this error..

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Brian/Desktop/BitmapBuilder.py", line 1, in 
    import os, shutil, Image, brianutils, sys
ImportError: No module named Image

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show the whole script? I assume you probably meant `from PIL import Image`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is saying that Image is not a module. Either it doesn't exist or it isn't in Python's path or the directory in which your script is.